# Plotting just the endpoint of quiver

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot a block of points with small deviations from their equilibrium states. Using `quiver` it would look like this:

[image]

And now I want to plot just markers located on the arrow tips. How to do that?

Input data are U and V deviations (on cartesian axes), getting the X,Y coordinates of vector origins is not a problem.

Comment: If you know the X, Y origins of the point and the U, V deviations, then you know the endpoints, dont you? Then just plot them using `plot(x,y,'.')`

Comment: @AnderBiguri But `quiver` applies a scale to those `U`, `V`. You'd have to include that scale, which is not known a priori

Comment: @LuisMendo well, but quiver has a `scale` input option!

Comment: @AnderBiguri But that scale only multiplies the internally computed scale. Try it

Comment: @LuisMendo Cant at the moment. Hummm, then I guess there are only 2 options: 1) reverse engineer the internal scale (maybe `edit quiver` ?) 2)plot the arrows with something else. There are several FEX submissions. Dont have Matlab at the moment to play with it unfortunately.

Comment: @Ander I followed the `edit quiver` route! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply use something like `plot(X+U, Y+V, 'o')` because [`quiver`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) applies an **automatically computed scale** to `U` and `V` so that all arrows fit nicely in the figure. You need to include that scale.

Looking into `quiver`'s code and replicating the part that computes that scale, you can proceed as follows:

```
%// Example data
x = rand(1,20);
y = rand(1,20);
u = rand(1,20);
v = rand(1,20);

%// Taken from "quiver.m". Computes autoscale
if min(size(x))==1, n=sqrt(numel(x)); m=n; else [m,n]=size(x); end
delx = diff([min(x(:)) max(x(:))])/n;
dely = diff([min(y(:)) max(y(:))])/m;
del = delx.^2 + dely.^2;
if del>0
    len = sqrt((u.^2 + v.^2)/del);
    maxlen = max(len(:));
else
    maxlen = 0;
end
if maxlen>0
    autoscale = 0.9 / maxlen;
else
    autoscale = 0.9;
end

%// quiver plot
quiver(x, y, u, v)
hold on

%// plot marker at arrow tips, including computed autoscale
plot(x+autoscale*u, y+autoscale*v, 'o')
```

If you **specify a scale argument** to `quiver`, that argument is a factor that multiplies the internally computed scale. So you have to include that in `plot` as well:

```
%// quiver plot including manual scale factor
quiver(x, y, u, v, .5)
hold on

%// plot marker at arrow tips, including computed autoscale and manual scale
plot(x+.5*autoscale*u, y+.5*autoscale*v, 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I would have robbed you this answer if I had Matlab :P Good one

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks :-)