# Cartopy: Can't plot vector field with uncertainties (and related questions)

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I've been trying for a while now to plot vector field with uncertainty ellipses in Cartopy. The idea is that if I have a location (lat/lon) and a vector (wind speed, for example), but that vector has an uncertainty (measured in standard deviation, for example), then I'd like to plot an ellipses around the tip of the arrow indicating that uncertainty. In GMT, `psvelo` does the trick, my goal is [something like this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/GPS-velocities-and-their-95-confidence-ellipses-in-a-Eurasia-fixed-reference-frame_fig1_331309175).

This is the same question as has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418479/how-to-plot-a-vector-field-with-error-ellipse-using-cartopy) - I'm reopening it because I think that if someone can help me understand transforms better and I can find the location of the tip of the arrow, I can plot the error ellipse myself. Plus, some Matplotlib/Cartopy functionality might have changed in the last 4 years.

So, here's what I tried so far:

1. Making a map, using quiver to plot the vectors, and then trying to access some sort of scale parameter in the returned `Quiver` object. I couldn't find anything useful, and even though the `scale` attribute looked like it would've been the right thing, it turned out never to be set unless I set it myself.
2. If I do set the scaling myself, I don't know how to do this if my location and vector have different units, and both are obviously not related to the axis width. For example, if I decided that I want to have a 50 m/s long vector at 10°E, 40°N, to be a certain fraction of the width of the axis, what would my `scale` parameter be? Me trying out random combinations of transformations has not gotten any results. (The idea here then being, if I can figure out that relation, then I am one step closer to knowing where to put the ellipse.)
3. I've tried to figure out `quiver` 's autoscaling to see how I can "predict" what it's going to do internally, and then use that to know where the tip of the arrow is. Sadly, it's [not as straightforward as the Matlab variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32436528/plotting-just-the-endpoint-of-quiver), so I failed at that as well.
4. Lastly, I also don't understand why I can't use `cartopy.crs.Geodetic()` as my source coordinate system. The error I get is `invalid transform: Spherical quiver is not supported -  consider using PlateCarree/RotatedPole.` From reading the Cartopy documentation, wouldn't that be the appropriate one if my vector's location is measured in latitude, longitude and altitude?

Here's an MWE:

```py
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
# data
lon, lat = np.array([10, 10.5]), np.array([40, 40])
east, north = np.array([0, 50]), np.array([50, 0])
# map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": ccrs.Mercator()})
ax.set_extent([7, 13, 38, 42], ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.coastlines("50m")
q = ax.quiver(lon, lat, east, north, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.show()
```

I really think this is a feature that Cartopy should have, as it is one of the biggest hurdles I've encountered so far when using Python for geoscience applications. Currently, the only approach I know is to write a GMT script file from within my Python program, and run GMT with a Python system call, and that's really a pain.

I know that [GMT is developing their own Python interface](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/pygmt), but they haven't even incorporated all the basic functionality, so it's anyone's guess when they will get to `psvelo`...

Thanks for all your help and tips,

PBB

Comment: This can be now done using pyGMT:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67649045/13890678

Answer (score 1):

Well the hard part about this is the matplotlib part. If I were trying to make this, I'd focus on that before making it work in Cartopy. Technically, the point you need is somewhere in the set of paths generated by the `quiver` command (located in `q._paths` in your MWE). A simpler solution would be to use `pivot='tip'` so that the point of the arrow is always located at the `(x,y)` point.

The error you're getting from Cartopy when you try to use `Geodetic` is because doing everying correctly when working on a sphere involves more complicated math--thus not everything works with `Geodetic`. If instead you use `PlateCarree`, it will treat lon/lat as Cartesian coordinates on a plane.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! So does that mean the `Geodetic` error at some point will be fixed as the Cartopy team includes more math, or is what I wanted just mathematically undefined?

Comment: Also, I had a look at `q._paths` - I'm still diving in a bit more but from what I can tell, it's actually empty until I produce and show a figure. That means I can't use that attribute if I want a (non-interactive, non-GUI) script to produce the output. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I've not looked, so I'm not sure what more `Geodetic` needs. You could look at the code for `q._make_verts` to see what's going on and know how to replicate it.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the q._paths variables @DopplerShift! I am facing a relative similar problems, it would be great to have your feedback if you have time [[my post is here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793436/get-coordinates-of-quiver-arrow-tip-and-bottom-when-plotting-in-uv-mode). Thank you

Comment: @PBB Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not, sadly. Your post with the transformations making it work for the `'xy'` format already goes a long way, though. At the worst, one would have to come up with a user-defined conversion from figure to xy to uv space.
Edit: I just saw your post on PyGMT's Github, nice, and will upvote that!

Comment: @PBB Yes instead of waiting to fix this in matplotlib, I thought I should give a try with *pygmt* :-) I will try to get some help to implement the GMT ```velo``` function [(more details here)](https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/latest/supplements/geodesy/velo.html). I will let you know if I manage to make it works!