# Get coordinates of quiver arrow (tip and bottom) when plotting in 'uv' mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

### What I am trying to do

I would like to be able to get the coordinate of the quiver arrow when plotting in 'uv' mode in order to re-use this data to plot other shapes (e.g. ellipse).

### The problem

This issue is also related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679029/cartopy-cant-plot-vector-field-with-uncertainties-and-related-questions). In this post, the answers mention using the `._paths` quiver variable to get the coordinate of the arrow. However, there are no indications about how to do it.

Does someone have a solution to access the coordinates associated with the top and bottom of the arrow in a ‘uv’ plotting mode? There are plenty of variables in `q._paths` and I cannot see which one is relevant.

### Code for reproduction

The code below work perfectly fine in 'xy' mode:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

#-------------------------------------
# Variable definition
colsec = 'royalblue'
colvec = 'salmon'
colellipse = 'limegreen'
x = np.array([ 0.00789308, -0.0773587 ,  0.03353797, -0.06185714, -0.13095092,
        0.03280368,  0.04775701, -0.08124051, -0.02894444, -0.02834356,
       -0.1457362 , -0.00628834,  0.09627607])
y = np.array([-0.03668553,  0.05931522, -0.04041772, -0.00866234, -0.00539877,
       -0.14787117, -0.21553271, -0.15741139, -0.1417963 , -0.00887117,
        0.02207362, -0.11979755, -0.28635583])
meanx = np.mean(x)
meany = np.mean(y)

# ellipse parameter
ell_radius_x = 0.54
ell_radius_y = 1.30
scale_x = 0.07
scale_y = 0.1

#-------------------------------------
# 'xy' plot

posx1 = 0
posy1 = 0
    
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.scatter(x,y,color='blue')

# Quiver plot
Qv = ax.quiver(posx1, posy1, meanx,  meany,
              angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1,
              color='black')

# Basic ellipse definition
ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0),
        width=ell_radius_x * 2,
        height=ell_radius_y * 2,
        facecolor='none',
        edgecolor='red')

center=(meanx + posx1, meany + posy1)

# Transformation of the ellipse according to external parameters (obtained from various statistics on the data)
transf = transforms.Affine2D() \
        .rotate_deg(45) \
        .scale(scale_x, scale_y) \
        .translate(*center)
ellipse.set_transform(transf + ax.transData)
    
# Plot of the ellipse
ax.plot(*center,'x',color='g',markersize=12)    
    
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
```

We got the expected outcome:
[image: ellipse and quiver 'xy' mode]

Now when I switch to 'uv' mode (my quiver position has a different unit), I cannot reproduce the same plot, although I tried playing with scaling factor. The code below gives me this outcome:
[image]

```py
#-------------------------------------
# 'uv' plot (variables are defined previously)

# Scale factor for quiver and ellipse plot
scalefac = 2

posx1 = np.array(-12.633)
posy1 = np.array(57.533)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.scatter(posx1,posy1,color='blue')

Qv = ax.quiver(posx1, posy1, meanx*scalefac,  meany*scalefac,
              scale=1, scale_units='width',
              color='black')

# Basic ellipse definition
ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0),
        width=ell_radius_x * 2,
        height=ell_radius_y * 2,
        facecolor='none',
        edgecolor='red')

# Transformation of the ellipse according to external parameters (obtained from various statistics on the data)
center=(meanx*scalefac + posx1, meany*scalefac + posy1)
transf = transforms.Affine2D() \
        .rotate_deg(45) \
        .scale(scale_x*scalefac, scale_y*scalefac) \
        .translate(*center)
ellipse.set_transform(transf + ax.transData)
    
# Plot of the ellipse
ax.plot(*center,'x',color='g',markersize=12)    
    
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
```

`Qv._paths` doesn't return a variable easy to understand:

```py
print(Qv._paths)
[Path(array([[ 0.00357682, -0.00112643],
       [-0.03897025, -0.13622912],
       [-0.03069018, -0.13490515],
       [-0.05268492, -0.1672941 ],
       [-0.05215112, -0.12814659],
       [-0.0461239 , -0.13397627],
       [-0.00357682,  0.00112643],
       [ 0.00357682, -0.00112643]]), None)]
```

I guess the scaling information I need is somewhere in `Qv._paths` but it is not clear to me where. The idea would be to have a robust method so I could change the scaling associated with my variable `scalefac`. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an issue related to the one asked by @PBB [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679029/cartopy-cant-plot-vector-field-with-uncertainties-and-related-questions)

Comment: The question might be obvious (I don't know anything about uv) but I took a quick look at the documentation. Why is the `scale_units` set to width?

Comment: Could it be that you are missing the `angles=uv` argument in your second plot?

Comment: @zwep sorry I should have indicated it for consistency but `angles=uv` is the default

Comment: @Mercury thx for the asking more information. The main difference between case 2 and case 1 is that in case 2, the units for plotting (u. v units) are not the same than the x and y units

Comment: @Ihoupert great question - poked around for a bit and don't have an answer for you. It seems that setting `width='xy'` gets the magnitude of the vector correct, but the angle is off by a bit. I hope that can help

Comment: Setting both angles and scale_units to 'xy' makes it perfect, but I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: The main problem here seems to be that the ellipse is in cartesian or x/y units while the arrow is in u/v units. Because of this, the geometric transforms aren't working as intended (they do work perfectly when both arrow and ellipse are in same units).

Answer (score 1):

After taking another look at the doc, I suddenly figured it out. Let me plot a dummy example, for easier understanding.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.xlim(-12.8,-12.6)
plt.ylim(57.2,57.6)

x1, y1 = -12.633, 57.533
x2, y2 = -12.7, 57.4
angle = np.arctan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
D = np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
U, V = D*np.cos(angle), D*np.sin(angle)
ax.scatter(x2, y2, marker='x', s=100, color='k')
Qv1 = ax.quiver(x1, y1, -U, -V, angles='uv', scale=1, scale_units='xy', color='black')
Qv2 = ax.quiver(x1, y1, -U, -V, angles='xy', scale=1, scale_units='xy', color='red')
```

Consider `(x2, y2)` analogous to the center of a hypothetical ellipse. We can calculate the angle and the U, V components with simple vector math. Plotting the above gives:

[image: Qv1 and Qv2]

Note how the quiver in uv angles is off by just a bit, same as the example in the question. However, if you read the documentation in matplotlib's docs, it says:

> 'uv': The arrow axis aspect ratio is 1 so that if U == V the orientation of the arrow on the plot is 45 degrees counter-clockwise from the horizontal axis (positive to the right).

The arrow's axis is independent of the x,y axis in uv mode, and this axis has an aspect ratio of 1. So naturally, if your plot has an aspect ratio of 1, the arrow should match perfectly!

```
plt.xlim(-12.8,-12.4)
plt.ylim(57.2,57.6)
```

Under this xlim and ylim setting, if I run my previous dummy plot, we'd get:

[image: Matching Qv]

Going back to your example, you need to change scale_units to 'xy' and simply set an xlim, ylim with an aspect ratio of 1.

```
#-------------------------------------
# 'uv' plot (variables are defined previously)

# Scale factor for quiver and ellipse plot
scalefac = 2

posx1 = np.array(-12.633)
posy1 = np.array(57.533)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.scatter(posx1,posy1,color='blue')

Qv = ax.quiver(posx1, posy1, meanx*scalefac,  meany*scalefac,
              angles='uv', scale=1, scale_units='xy',
              color='black')

# Basic ellipse definition
ellipse = Ellipse((0, 0),
        width=ell_radius_x * 2,
        height=ell_radius_y * 2,
        facecolor='none',
        edgecolor='red')

# Transformation of the ellipse according to external parameters (obtained from various statistics on the data)
center=(meanx*scalefac + posx1, meany*scalefac + posy1)
transf = transforms.Affine2D() \
        .rotate_deg(45) \
        .scale(scale_x*scalefac, scale_y*scalefac) \
        .translate(*center)
ellipse.set_transform(transf + ax.transData)
    
# Plot of the ellipse
ax.plot(*center,'x',color='g',markersize=12)    
    
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.xlim(-13,-12.5)
plt.ylim(57.1, 57.6)
```

[image: Correct Qv]

Maybe an additional warning or note should be added in the matplotlib docs, because I think this isn't really obvious at first glance.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the behavior of scale_units, I may open an issue for adding an additional warning. 
Unfortunately, I  will have to use this function on situation where the aspect ratio of the ax will not be 1 (on top of a map). Could you propose a more generic solution which would scale the length of the quiver arrow so it match the ax aspect ratio? For example if your xlim=[-13.5,-12] and ylim=[57.3,57.6]?

Comment: At this point, I'd say what you want isn't possible, by virtue of violating the definition. You want to plot in 'uv' mode, but 'uv' mode is specifically defined as having a fixed aspect ratio of 1. This cannot be changed. You also desire to affect 'scale' somehow so that the arrow works correctly -- however, scale has absolutely zero control on the aspect ratio. scale_units can change the aspect ratio of the arrow, but it has a set of fixed settings: you cannot input scale-x and scale-y values to affect the arrow.

Comment: Other than semantics, is there any problem if you simply plot the quiver in angles='xy' mode? You'll always get your desired plot if you do that. Although your units are uv and not xy, you're effectively attempting to treat them as xy, since you're plotting them on the xy plane and scaling them according to the x-y axis aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I will have to think more about how to implement this solution in my specific case when my ax aspect ratio is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around by developing a new function for the [pyGMT package](https://www.pygmt.org/dev/gallery/index.html). A gallery example can be found here: https://www.pygmt.org/dev/gallery/seismology/velo_arrow_ellipse.html#sphx-glr-gallery-seismology-velo-arrow-ellipse-py

```py
import pandas as pd
import pygmt

fig = pygmt.Figure()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "x": [0, -8, 0, -5, 5, 0],
        "y": [-8, 5, 0, -5, 0, -5],
        "east_velocity": [0, 3, 4, 6, -6, 6],
        "north_velocity": [0, 3, 6, 4, 4, -4],
        "east_sigma": [4, 0, 4, 6, 6, 6],
        "north_sigma": [6, 0, 6, 4, 4, 4],
        "correlation_EN": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5],
        "SITE": ["0x0", "3x3", "4x6", "6x4", "-6x4", "6x-4"],
    }
)
fig.velo(
    data=df,
    region=[-10, 8, -10, 6],
    pen="0.6p,red",
    uncertaintycolor="lightblue1",
    line=True,
    spec="e0.2/0.39/18",
    frame=["WSne", "2g2f"],
    projection="x0.8c",
    vector="0.3c+p1p+e+gred",
)

fig.show()
```