# fill color between arrowheads in a quiver plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a few arrows in a quiver plot, and I wonder if there is a way to fill the shape traced between the arrowheads with color.
The quiver plots look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 40 ) 
R = 5.0
x = R * np.cos( theta ) 
y = R * np.sin( theta ) 
m2_x = 9.0
m2_y = 9.0
u = -(x - m2_x)/((m2_x - x)**2 + (m2_y - y)**2)**2 
v = -(y - m2_y)/((m2_x - x)**2 + (m2_y - y)**2)**2 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
ax.quiver(x,y,u,v, headwidth=2, headlength=5, width=0.005)
ax.set_xlim((-20,20))
ax.set_ylim((-20,20))
```

I want to fill the circle-ish shape traced by the arrow heads with color, or at least connect the arrowheads with a line. Seems like it should be simple but I couldn't find how yet.

Comment: Using `ax.plot(x+3000*u,y+3000*v)` seems to be working but I have no idea why the scaling factor should be 3000. My intuition is that it has to do with the `xlim` and `ylim` that you are using (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793436/get-coordinates-of-quiver-arrow-tip-and-bottom-when-plotting-in-uv-mode))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quiver` returns a [specialized `PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.quiver.Quiver.html) for arrows. The tip of the arrow head is vertice #3 of each arrow. From this collection we get the coordinates of the arrowheads and create a [`PathPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.PathPatch.html) to add to the Axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

theta = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 40 ) 
R = 5.0
x = R * np.cos( theta ) 
y = R * np.sin( theta ) 
m2_x = 9.0
m2_y = 9.0
u = -(x - m2_x)/((m2_x - x)**2 + (m2_y - y)**2)**2 
v = -(y - m2_y)/((m2_x - x)**2 + (m2_y - y)**2)**2 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
q = ax.quiver(x,y,u,v, headwidth=2, headlength=5, width=0.005)
ax.set_xlim((-20,20))
ax.set_ylim((-20,20))

# draw the quiver to get the coordinates of the arrows
fig.draw_without_rendering()

# get x,y in display coords (pixels)
xy_disp = q.transform.transform(q.properties()['offsets'])

# get arrow heads in display coords, relative to x,y
heads_rel = np.vstack([p.vertices[3] for p in q.properties()['paths']])
heads_rel_disp = q.properties()['transform'].transform(heads_rel)

# get arrow heads in absolute data coordinates
heads = q.transform.inverted().transform(xy_disp + heads_rel_disp)

# draw patch
ax.add_patch(mpatches.PathPatch(mpath.Path(heads), fc='r', alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I get an error executing the code: ``` ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate``` for the line ```heads_rel = np.vstack([p.vertices[3] for p in q.properties()['paths']]) ```

Comment: hm, what matplotlib version do you use (example works for 3.5.0)? What is the output of `q.properties()['paths']`?

Comment: Yes, I updated my matplotlib and it works now perefectly! Thank you!!!